# Time step independence of Molecular Dynamics code

Tags: c++, simulation, modeling

I am writing a basic MD code in C++ using LJ potential for an NVE system. The starting configuration is FCC and the starting velocities are randomly generated.

I am facing a strange problem in that the evolution of the system seems to be independent of the time step I implement, it is my understanding that the energy losses are smaller for small time steps and larger for larger time steps. However I am getting the same result at the end of the simulation in terms of energy whether I run (0.0001step)*(10000steps) or 0.001*1000 and so on.

The entire code is to big for me to post here, so I am posting what I think is relevant and leaving out binning etc., kindly let me know if any additional information is required. I have been through countless codes available online and though they look similar to mine I just am not able to figure out what the difference is and where I am going wrong.

The main cpp contains the following loop

```
for (int i=0; i<t;i++)
{
    potential_calc(neighlist,fromfile, run_parameters,i);//calculating the force fields
    velverlet(neighlist,fromfile, run_parameters, bin, dt);//calculating the velocities
}
```

The declarations of the 2 cpp files for potential calculation & verlet integration are

```
void potential_calc(neighborlist_type *neighlist, config_type *fromfile, potential *run_parameters, int t)

void velverlet(neighborlist_type *neighlist, config_type *fromfile, potential *run_parameters, bin_type *bin, double dt)
```

The code for calculating the force - potential_calc.cpp is below

```
for (long i=0; i<fromfile->N; i++)
{
long atom_p=i;


for (long j=0; j<neighlist[i].countsn; j++)
    {

    long atom_s=neighlist[i].numb[j];

    for (int k=0; k<Dim; k++)
        {
        dist[k]= fromfile->r[atom_p][k] - (fromfile->r[atom_s][k] + neighlist[atom_p].xyz[j][k]*fromfile->L[k]);
//the .xyz indicates the image being considered real or mirror(if mirror then in which direction)
        }
    disp2 = pow(dist[0],2)+pow(dist[1],2)+pow(dist[2],2);
    if (disp2<rb2)
        {
        int c1=fromfile->c[atom_p];
        int c2=fromfile->c[atom_s];
        double long force_temp;
        disp=pow(disp2,0.5);

        sig_r6=pow(run_parameters->sigma[c1-1][c2-1]/disp,6);//(sigma/r)^6
        sig_r8=pow(run_parameters->sigma[c1-1][c2-1]/disp,8);//(sigma/r)^8

        run_parameters->pe[atom_p] += (4*run_parameters->epsilon[c1-1][c2-1]*((sig_r6*sig_r6)-sig_r6)) - potential_correction[c1-1][c2-1];

        force_temp=(-1*((48*run_parameters->epsilon[c1-1][c2-1])/pow(run_parameters->sigma[c1-1][c2-1],2)*((sig_r6*sig_r8)-((sig_r8)*0.5))));
        for (int k=0; k<Dim;k++)
            {
            run_parameters->force[atom_p][k]+=force_temp*(-1*dist[k]);
            }
        }
    }
//calculating kinetic energy
run_parameters->ke[atom_p] = 0.5*(pow(fromfile->v[atom_p][0],2)+pow(fromfile->v[atom_p][1],2)+pow(fromfile->v[atom_p][2],2));

}
```

Once the force calculation is done it goes to the updation of velocity and position in the velverlet.cpp

```
for (long i=0; i<fromfile->N; i++)
{
for (int j=0; j<Dim; j++)
    {
    fromfile->v[i][j] += (dt*run_parameters->force[i][j]);
    }
}

for (long i=0; i<fromfile->N; i++)
{
for (int j=0; j<Dim; j++)
    {
    fromfile->r[i][j] += dt*fromfile->v[i][j];
    }
}
```

There may be slight differences in how velocity verlet is implemented by different people but I can't figure out how I am getting time step independent results.

Please help. Any input is appreciated
Sorry if any formatting/tagging is wrong, this is the first time I am posting here

Comment: Can you please post the code for the loop that contains this (the loop that will run once for each "time step") thanks

Comment: @MagikM18 - I have edited the post to add the main loop for each time step and the declaration to signify the pointers sent. Thank you. Let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Where is `dt` calculated?

Comment: dt- value/increment of each time step & t-number of time steps both are user input. I intend to run for 1s in different ways - 100steps*0.01increment, 1000*0.001, 10000*0.0001 and so on to get better energy conservation with smaller discretization of time

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused, are you getting the same result for the same total time simulated (for example, for 1 second no matter how many steps you subdivide it into)?

Comment: yes! that is correct

Comment: Sorry to point out the obvious, but aren't they supposed to be equal? `double` is quite accurate, so changing the time resolution shouldn't have a very large change. Try using step sizes that are even smaller, such as nanoseconds.

Comment: smaller time steps should invariably lead to lower energy losses and smaller fluctuations in energy with (real) time, I have tried the intervals between 10^-2 to 10^-7 and gotten the exact same results against time

Comment: Here is my understanding of what you are trying to do, please correct me if I'm wrong: when calculate for 100 steps of. 01s each, you loop through 100 times, each time calculating the changes in variables over .01s of simulated time. Are you expecting more accurate results with smaller steps? If not that, then what?

Comment: that is correct i loop through 100 times and plot the energy over these 100 loops similarly for an increment of 0.001s I do 1000 times, the energy fluctuations with time are supposed to be better/lower for the second case than the first one or at the very least when comparing time steps of 0.01 and 0.0000001 which isn't the case in my code

Comment: Would you mind posting these output values? Your code doesn't appear to use any square root or trigonometry operations, so if your results are rather simple (i.e. "1.5" or something like that), the `double` is too accurate for adding more iterations to give you a different result; if anything, they would give you a less accurate result. On the other hand, if the results are more complicated, i.e. non-terminating floating-point numbers, then the number of iterations should be making a difference.